# Why does Chrome pretend I'm sending a X-DNS-Prefetch-Control header?

Tags: google-chrome, http

I'm running a server that always responds to all requests with

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Test
```

But Chrome DevTools shows that I'm sending a header:
[X-DNS-Prefetch-Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RtcD.png). When I click "view source", Chrome shows that I am indeed not sending any headers.

[image: A screenshot of Chrome Devtools, that shows no response headers].

Why does Chrome DevTools show this header?